# Laravel authorize always returns false

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, axios, policy

I'm having some problems with Policies on Laravel. The problem is, my create policy always return false, no matter what I do, even when I explicity make it "return true", it will give me 403 forbidden.
Its important to mention that I'm making a POST request with axios to my MenuController@store function, then on my store function I'm calling $this->authorize('create') from my Policies...

Take a look:

**MenuController@store**

```
public function store(StoreMenuRequest $request, Shop $shop)
{
    $this->authorize('create', [Auth::user(), $shop]);
    $menu = new Menu;

    $menu->name = $request->name;
    $menu->slug = str_slug($menu->name, "-");
    $menu->shop_id = $shop->id;

    $menu->save();

    return $menu->load('items');
}
```

**MenuPolicy**

```
public function create(User $user, Shop $shop)
{
    return $user->owns($shop);
}
```

* Note that, even when I do "return true" it will not work...

**Axios request**

```
addNewMenu()
            {   
                var _this = this;
                axios.post('{{ Route('chef.menus.store', $shop) }}', {
                    name : this.menuName
                }).then(function(response){
                    // Menu saved
                }).catch(function(error){
                    // Errors
                });
            }
```

No matter what I do, I'll always get false from my create policy.
Note that, when I remove my $this->authorize() function from my controller, all works fine, so I suppose that the authorization is the problem, right?

My AuthServiceProvider seems to be okay:

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    'App\Shop' => 'App\Policies\ShopPolicy',
    'App\Menu' => 'App\Policies\MenuPolicy'
];
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? :(
Really appreciate any help.
Thank you very much!

**** EDIT ****

For anyone that may be struggling with it, I figured out what was happening, since I'm doing this verification on the MenuPolicy that is linked to a Menu model, and I'm passing a Shop instance to the create() method, I guess that it won't work, I may misunderstood how the poilcy work...
So to fix that, I just created a "createMenu()" function inside my Shop policy, this way I can pass a Shop instance to the method and it will work just fine :), cause I just need to verify if the Shop is owned by the current user.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel docs there is [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#via-controller-helpers) example:

```
$this->authorize('create',  $shop);
```

So you shouldn't need to pass in user

Comment: Thank you for the reply!, but if I do this, then the authorize will always return true! haha, even if I do "return false", it will kind be ignored

Comment: does your route have auth middleware? and you get the user with `dd(Auth::user())`?

Comment: Yea, my route have the auth middleware, and my Auth::user() and my $shop are fine :(, I did dd() on my store() function and then read with console.log() on my axios request... both are fine. Its really strange